# Printing lines according to their columns in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, nawk

i know it is very basic question but im total new in shell scripting

i a txt file called 'berkay' and content of it is like

```
03:05:16 debug blablabla1
03:05:18 error blablablablabla2
05:42:14 degub blabblablablabal
06:21:24 debug balbalbal1
```

I want to print the lines whose second column is error so the output will be

> 03:05:18 error blablablablabla2

I am thinking about something like " if nawk { $2}" but i need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this for example:

```
$ awk '$2=="error"' file
03:05:18 error blablablablabla2
```

Why is this working? Because when the condition is true, `awk` automatically performs its default behaviour: `{print $0}`. So there is no need to explicitly write it.

Comment: No, the `$` just shows the prompt. You just need to copy from `awk`

Comment: Why not just `$2=="error"`? I don't see why an RE comparison would be useful here.

Comment: You are totally right, @EdMorton, I just messed up. Updated with a proper solution. Thanks!

Comment: thanks dude i did "awk '{ if($2 == "error") print $0;}' berkay" and it worked. im loving shell scripting gradually

Comment: Nice, @abidinberkay Note that my solution is more "idiomatic". That is, it takes some `awk` default ways of handling to skip some parts like `if ()` --> `()` or `{print $0}`.

Comment: @abidinberkay You could add 50 more redundant lines of code and 10 more spurious semi-colons to it and still get the output you want and it still wouldn't be the solution. See what fedorqui posted - that is how to solve this problem in awk. If that didn't work for you then you should spend the time now to figure out what you are doing wrong or what is broken about your awk. Maybe you're using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris).